# How Do I Create a "Network Glow" Effect in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, gimp

Trying to create a glow effect similar to the following image on Freepik using Inkscape:

[image: Hand network glow]

https://www.freepik.com/free-vector/polygonal-wireframe-business-strategy-composition-with-glittering-images-human-hand-with-chess-pieces-with-text_7379609.htm#page=1&query=graph%20network&position=24

I can do the network part fine it is the background glow that is eluding me. I also have GIMP if that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, glows are easier to achieve using raster software like GIMP, so I wouldn't use Inkscape for this.

Also, the initial graphic looks like it could be wireframe low poly 3D models made using software like Blender. In fact the whole thing could have been made in Blender or similar 3D software, including the glow effect.

Anyhoo, in GIMP, you could try this.  This isn't a tutorial, just the basic steps.

1. Colourize the graphic to make it blue.
2. Duplicate the image layer, add some Gaussian blur, and change the blending mode to Addition.
3. Duplicate that layer for a stronger effect.
4. Add a new layer from visible and do a curves adjustment to create a bit more contrast
5. Paint some point lights at line intersections with a small soft edged brush.
6. Use the Free select tool to add a mask to a transparent layer, and paint some soft blurs inside using a large soft edged brush set to low opacity

Something like this example below. This is just a very quick example to show the basics.

[image]

Maybe finish off, by painting some background dark blue glow with a large soft edged low opacity brush, then do a new layer from visible and do another curves adjustment to make it pop more.

[image]

Comment: Yes the example is a 3d model but my graphic isn't. Thanks for the answer.